# Can OpenWRT manage separated switch (or other device)

Tags: networking, switch, openwrt

Is it possible using single OpenWRT "main" instance to manage a managed switch with some management protocol, or any other device like for example access point with second instance of OpenWRT?

Comment: moved from: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69179/can-openwrt-manage-separated-switch-or-other-device?noredirect=1

Comment: This would be documented in the OpenWRT documentation if it were possible. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear your assumptions about docs are to optimistic